# javascript : closing the window on a button click

Tags: javascript, web-applications, struts

I need to close a window on a button click using javascript .

However , before closing the window , I want to submit the form (I am using struts2. It is a java web app).

So how do I submit the data for saving and close the window at the same time . It is a pop up kind of window . The below is the jquery code , I use to submit the form.

```
   function fnSubmit() {                
         $('#adminpopup').attr('action','submitPopupAction').submit();  
}
```

Edit : I have one more constraint here .  When I click on the submit button , the form gets submitted . In case there are errors while returning from the server side code , I will have to display the error message in the pop up . If it is successful , close the pop up .

I guess this cannot be achieved by simply calling javascript functions one after the other. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submit the form to the server.

If it is the same domain, return

```
<script>
window.close()
</script>
```

from the server

Answer (score 2):

You could use the JavaScript self.close() function (or window.close() for other windows), but it will show a security message if the window was not opened with window.open(). You should be able to call this after the form is submitted.

[Using window.close](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml)

Answer (score 1):

Just send the form and (on success) send a page back that merely issues `window.close`. This will only work if the window has been opened using `window.open`, so as a fallback option you should provide a human readable message in the window that says that they can safely close the popup window.

Answer (score -3):

Just add this after the `submit` line:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   window.close();
}, 1000);
```

This will give one second to the form to be submitted (enough time to ensure the request has been sent) then close the window.

Comment: How are you so sure that 1 s is enough to send the form? Even with a fast connection the server might be quite busy and not respond immediately.

Comment: @Marcel as far as I could see he does not need to see the response. Once the request has been sent it's enough, no need to wait for answer from the server.

Comment: AFAIK the browser will have to contact the server before it can send the form data. The form data might even be that big that it's impossible to send it in only one second. In short, that one second is merely a guess, you can't rely on it.

Comment: @Marcel OK fair enough. Leaving this as alternative way with its flaw explained in the comments.

Answer (score -3):

Try following:

Create a button and add there the onClick event. Close this window. Additionally connect the event ***un***load to the body tag. At this event submit the form.

Comment: This will not work in more standards compliant browsers like Opera; above all, it is very likely that the unload event will not run long enough to send the form.

Comment: How would that work? You cannot submit a form to the same page in onunload

Comment: As far as I know, the event onUnload is not outside of the HTML from W3C foundation. Or I'm not uptodate anymore?

Comment: You're correct, it is in the [DOM level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) spec. But my original points stands: the unload event will probably not run long enough (i.e., the browser will be closed prematurely) to submit the form.